# A terminal application that I can programatically grab text from

Tags: terminal-emulator, shell-extension

I want to be able to modify an application (imagine Cygwin) that allows me to grab whatever text is on screen.

Does such a library exist? Or is there an easy way to do it with existing software?

I mean fully programmatically, not clicking on the screen to copy.

The way I was going to do this originally was capture the window's framebuffer and then use character recognition to process the screen, but that seems like overkill.

If there is a way to do this with Windows/WSL that would be even better.

Comment: Did you try e.g. `screendump`?